# removing nested lambdas from function definition

Tags: scheme

I have to remove every `lambda` from the following code, and I can't use other functions in the global space. `(((f 1) 2) 3)` should produce `6`.

```
(define f (lambda (x)
            (lambda (y)
              (lambda (z)
                (+ x y z)))))
```

I have tried using `define` in `define`, but the problem is with the `(((f 1) 2) 3)` having to give `6`. I dont see how I can use the `2` and `3` inside function `f`, if they are given outside the function?  It is OK if the `lambda`s are “under the hood,” they just have to not be visible.

Comment: And what have you tried? please post the code you've written so far, and state how you plan to solve the problem, outline the ideas

Comment: Too keep how it's used you need nested procedures so it's possible to rewrite it to use define or cut but both are using lambda under the hood.

Comment: In Racket you can use the [curried function shorthand](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define.html#%28part._.Curried_.Function_.Shorthand%29) syntax for hiding the `lambda`s - although they will be still there, under the hood

Comment: @Jelte, if your question has been answered, then please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437).  Please don't edit the question with a message saying that it's been answered, as that's not part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(define (f x)
  (define (g y)
    (define (h z)
      (+ x y z))
    h)
  g)
```

or

```
(define (((f x) y) z)
  (+ x y z))
```

Comment: I really like the `(define (((f x) y) z) ...)` notation, but do note that, as discussed in the comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19585290/1281433), it may not be supported in all Schemes, and isn't necessarily well formed according to the grammar for definitions.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I added it 1) because I like and use it myself and 2) because the OP has tagged earlier questions with the `Racket` tag. But indeed it's not generally supported (Bigloo, for example, does not).